# Prune branches and automatically switch back to master if deleted in Git

Tags: git

I have multiple repositories that have branches I have merged changes from and deleted from the remote. I know if I run `git remote prune` it will automatically delete these branches, but if I happen to be on one of those branches, that branch will stay checked out. I have an update script that automatically syncs all my repositories with the remote, but I would like to be able to have it automatically switch back to master if the remote branch the local repository is on has been deleted. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To conditionally switch to master branch if current branch is not tracked anymore you can use `rev-parse`

```sh
git fetch
git rev-parse \
    --symbolic-full-name @{u} \
    >/dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    git stash
    git checkout master
fi

git remote prune origin
```

The [`@{u}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) here means *upstream* of current branch.

Comment: I guess the key point is that I would like to switch to master only if the current branch has been deleted. It looks like those commands will always switch to master.

Comment: Your answer didn't work for me, but I made my own version based on you answer that does work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of vsminkov's answer that works well:

```
git remote prune origin
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u} > /dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    git checkout master
fi
```